styling banner ad using capacitor/admob
I'm trying to make this banner like controllable its style so it can inline in the content of the app, I try using banner and reward add using
@capacitor-community/admob
and work perfectly fine. however, I'm struggling finding way to make it inline to the context as this overflow the app content.
I want to know if there is a way doing this because I'm struggling implementing the ad mob in the capacitor android app so I'm relying in the @capacitor-community/admob
import { AdMob } from "@capacitor-community/admob";
    const showAd = () => {
          AdMob.showBanner({
            adId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", // Test Banner Ad ID
            adSize: "ADAPTIVE_BANNER",
            position: "BOTTOM_CENTER",
          });
        };

and also the import { AdMob } from "@capacitor-community/admob"; support only the banner intertital and reward add? am i right. i tried the native advance not working
